# Calculating active days/months from overlapping dates

Tags: r, date, data.table, dplyr

I have data listing start and end dates for different products for a big number of customers. The intervals for different products can overlap or have time gaps between purchases:

```
library(lubridate)
library(Hmisc)
library(dplyr)

user_id <- c(rep(12, 8), rep(33, 5))

start_date <- dmy(Cs(31/10/2010,    18/12/2010, 31/10/2011, 18/12/2011, 27/03/2014, 18/12/2014, 27/03/2015, 18/12/2016, 01/07/1992, 20/08/1993, 28/10/1999, 31/01/2006, 26/08/2016))

end_date <- dmy(Cs(31/10/2011,  18/12/2011, 28/04/2014, 18/12/2014, 27/03/2015, 18/12/2016, 27/03/2016, 18/12/2017,
               01/07/2016,  16/08/2016, 15/11/2012, 28/02/2006, 26/01/2017))

data <- data.frame(user_id, start_date, end_date)

data
   user_id start_date   end_date
1       12 2010-10-31 2011-10-31
2       12 2010-12-18 2011-12-18
3       12 2011-10-31 2014-04-28
4       12 2011-12-18 2014-12-18
5       12 2014-03-27 2015-03-27
6       12 2014-12-18 2016-12-18
7       12 2015-03-27 2016-03-27
8       12 2016-12-18 2017-12-18
9       33 1992-07-01 2016-07-01
10      33 1993-08-20 2016-08-16
11      33 1999-10-28 2012-11-15
12      33 2006-01-31 2006-02-28
13      33 2016-08-26 2017-01-26
```

**I'd like to calculate the total number of active days or months during which he/she held any the products**.

It wouldn't be a problem if the products ALWAYS overlapped as then I could simply take

```
data %>% 
group_by(user_id) %>% 
dplyr::summarize(time_diff = max(end_date) - min(start_date))
```

However, as you can see in user 33, products don't always overlap and their interval has to be added separately to all 'overlapped' intervals.

Is there a quick and elegant way to code it, hopefully in `dplyr`?

Comment: thanks @J_F for adding appropriate packages to my code!

Comment: I don't see a product_id. If each line contains a different product then in your specific example there would be no days at which a client held all the products. Or do I misunderstand you?

Comment: hi @Edwin, maybe I type of product is irrelevant here, I just wanted to calculate the total number of active days when a user held any product. I'll edit my post, as probably my wording was a bit misleading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use functions from `dplyr` to count the total number of days. The following example expands each time period, and then removes duplicated dates. Finally count the total row number for each `user_id`.

```
data2 <- data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  do(data_frame(user_id = .$user_id, 
     Date = seq(.$start_date, .$end_date, by = 1))) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  count(user_id)
```

Comment: this is exactly what I've been after, thank you @ycw! A quick question, though, because you're expanding each interval in the data frame, is it feasible to apply it efficiently to big data sets (millions of users)?

Comment: @KasiaKulma I don't know if it will work efficiently on big data. You may want to test it.

Comment: @yvc, I'm testing it on big-ger data, ~18k rows. Your code will run 6% through and then stop returning the following error: `Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : wrong sign in 'by' argument`, any ideas what's causing it? I'm googling like crazy as we speak, but no luck so far...

Comment: Nevermind, I solved it! it turned out I have some rows where end_date < start_date and that's what was causing issues!

Answer (score 3):

Whats about using `IRanges` and `intersect`?

```
library(IRanges)
data %>% 
  group_by(user_id) %>% 
  summarise(days_held=sum(width(reduce(IRanges(as.numeric(start_date), as.numeric(end_date)))))) 
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  user_id active_days
    <dbl>       <int>
1      12        2606
2      33        8967
```

And here the benchmarks using  Nathan Wert's `big_data`. The IRange method seems to be a little bit faster.

```
my_result <- function(x) {
x %>% 
    group_by(user_id) %>% 
    summarise(days_held=sum(width(reduce(IRanges(as.numeric(start_date), as.numeric(end_date)))))) 
}


library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  a <- my_result(big_data),
  b <- my_answer(big_data), times=2
)
Unit: seconds
                     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 a <- my_result(big_data) 14.97008 14.97008 14.98896 14.98896 15.00783 15.00783     2  a 
 b <- my_answer(big_data) 17.59373 17.59373 17.76257 17.76257 17.93140 17.93140     2   b

all.equal(a, b)
[1] TRUE
```

## Edit

To visualize the ranges you also can plot the data...

```
library(Gviz)
library(GenomicRanges)
a <- sapply(split(data, data$user_id), function(x) {
  AnnotationTrack(start = as.numeric(x$start_date), end = as.numeric(x$end_date),
                  chromosome = "chrNA", stacking = "full", name = as.character(unique(x$user_id)))
})
plotTracks(trackList = a)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Making a `data.frame` is not very efficient, so you can save time by keeping the ranges as `Date` vectors.

```
multi_seq_date <- Vectorize(seq.Date, c('from', 'to'), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

data %>%
  group_by(user_id) %>%
  mutate(date_seq = multi_seq_date(start_date, end_date, by = 'day')) %>%
  summarise(days_held = length(unique(unlist(date_seq))))
```

*I'm sure there's a more idiomatic tidyverse way to write that, but I'm not a tidyverse guy.*

`multi_seq_date` will return a list of date sequences. Then it's just a matter of counting the unique days across that list. I ran this and ycw's answer on a large randomly-generated sample set:

```
# Making the data -----------------------------------
big_size <- 100000
starting_range <- seq(dmy('01-01-1990'), dmy('01-01-2017'), by = 'day')

set.seed(123456)
big_data <- data.frame(
  user_id    = sample(seq_len(round(big_size / 4)), big_size, replace = TRUE),
  start_date = sample(starting_range, big_size, replace = TRUE)
)
big_data$end_date <- big_data$start_date + round(runif(big_size, 1, 500))


# The actual process to test -------------------------
my_answer <- function(x) {
  multi_seq_date <- Vectorize(seq.Date, c('from', 'to'), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
  x %>%
    group_by(user_id) %>%
    mutate(date_seq = multi_seq_date(start_date, end_date, by = 'day')) %>%
    summarise(days_held = length(unique(unlist(date_seq))))
}
```

On my computer, `my_answer` took about 13 seconds.